# Batch - Delete folders

Tags: batch-file

First of all: I'm totally new to batch.

I want to write a batch file which deletes files and folders which are min. 5 days or older. This code works perfect with all files:

```
FORFILES /p "C:\Users\rs\Desktop\testbatch" /s /m *.* /d -5 /c "cmd /c if not @isdir==TRUE del @path"
```

But my folders are still here and I don't get how to delete them too if they are min. 5 days old. Can someone please give me a hint?

Cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch file to delete files older than N days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days)

Comment: Write a script below to the first line to delete the empty folders as well  "for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir /s /b /ad %1 ^| sort /r') do rd "%%d" 2>nul" . We assume that if a folder has 2 files , one is 2 days old and one is 6 days old, we just delete the file which is 6 days old. If all the files are more than 5 days old, delete the file and delete the directory. IF the first script works, use script mentioned to delete the empty folders.

Comment: @esac: not a duplicate, this is about deleting folders, or more specifically asking why the folders themselves are not deleted, but the files are.

Comment: @esac It's not a duplicate. I asked why my folders still exists :)

Comment: This 'how do i delete files older than x days' question is asked quite a bit on here. I see 6 in the Related sidebar. There are many examples of how to accomplish it. Another one is not needed. In fact this one specifically says to use rmdir which is the answer to this same question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517017/batch-file-to-delete-files-and-folder?rq=1

Comment: @esac Yes but I didn't found one that describes me why my folders still exists. I had a look at many of these posts but no one really helped me

Comment: @Roman : see this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517017/batch-file-to-delete-files-and-folder?rq=1 it is the same question and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`del` deletes the files, while you need to use `rmdir` for directories.

Comment: With `rmdir` you mean `rd`? Is there a difference if I write `rmdir` or `rd`?

Comment: No, it's the same. I don't know which is an alias of the other, but I know both do the same thing. `rmdir` increases readability (IMO) to understand that you are removing directories, though, as with `mkdir` and `md`.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you. So I got now `if not @isdir==TRUE rd /s /q @path` instead of `if not @isdir==TRUE del @path`. This should be correct, am I right? It doesn't seem to work because folders are still here (for testing it I add `/d -0` to file).

Comment: You can change it to `echo "rd /s /q @path"` to see what is it actually trying to delete.

Comment: I tried this and there comes an error that there are no files to delete

Comment: You may want to change `*.*` to `*`. You're not looking for files.

Comment: Nice, thanks. What a mistake >.< I just looked to the last part of the command line and forgot the first part. Thank you guy :)

Answer (score 1):

```
FORFILES /p "C:\Users\rs\Desktop\testbatch" /s /m *.* /d -5 /c "cmd /c if  @isdir==TRUE  rd /s /q  @path "
```

Comment: I have to use /s twice?

Comment: The second `/s` goes to `rd`, which if you `rd /?` means "Removes all directories and files in the specified directory in addition to the directory itself.  Used to remove a directory tree."

Comment: Okay, thanks. But it doesn't seem to work. I tried `/d -0` for test it but my folder is still here

Comment: there was one redundant `not` on if condition.

Comment: You mean I have to remove `not`?

Comment: yes (in the way the code is at the moment).Otherwise it will delete only the files.

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that this is necessary :)